# To get the only 5th record from a table in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table named Stud in which I have a column to store the total. Now I need to find the 5th largest total in total column. How to perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT total FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC) as RN, total FROM Stud
) T
WHERE RN=5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select total 
From
(SELECT total,
       row_number() over(order by total desc) as rn
From totalTable
)Z
Where rn=5
```

Also can be done using [**ROWNUM**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) pseudocolumn

```
Select total 
From
    (SELECT total
     FROM totalTable
     ORDER BY total desc
    )Z
Where ROWNUM=5
```